# Laravel or PHP foreach issue on DB::Table vs. Model::get()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-7, laravel-7

The code below works fine:

```
$data = Structures::select("id", "parent_id", "category", "type", "subType", "variant", "description")
        ->orderBy('category')
        ->orderBy('type')
        ->orderBy('subType')
        ->orderBy('variant')
        ->get() ;

        return $this->fillCategories($data) ;
```

The `fillCategories()` function fills a JSON tree with parent child relationships.

However, the code below, doesn't work.

```
  $data = DB::table("categories AS t1")
        ->select("t1.id", "t1.name AS category", "t2.id as typeId", "t2.name as type", "t3.id as subTypeId", "t3.name as subType", "t4.id as variantId", "t4.name as variant")
          ->leftJoin("categories AS t2", "t2.parent_id", "=", "t1.id")
          ->leftJoin("categories AS t3", "t3.parent_id", "=", "t2.id")
          ->leftJoin("categories AS t4", "t4.parent_id", "=", "t3.id")
            ->whereNull("t1.parent_id")
              ->orderBy("t1.name")
              ->orderBy("t2.name")
              ->orderBy("t3.name")
              ->orderBy("t4.name")
            ->get() ;

            foreach ($data as $v) {
              Log::info("cat: " . json_encode($v));
            }

        return $this->fillCategories($data) ;
```

The local log returns values, but when `$data` is passed to `fillCategories()` the foreach in the function ignores the `$data`!

Snippet of the `foreach` in `fillCategories()`

```
...
      $select = array() ;
      $child = array() ;

      $cat = null ;
      $type = null ;
      $sub = null ;
      $first = true ;

      $clear = true ;
      $label = null ;
      $value = null ;

      $prev = null ;

     Log::info("fillCat: data = " . json_encode($data)) ;

     foreach ($data as $v):

        Log::info("fillCat forloop: v($v->cat, $v->type, $v->subType, $v->variant)") ;

        $parent = null ;
        $isKid = false ;
        $isGrandKid = false ;

...
```

I'm assuming for now that passing `$data` to the function from `DB::table` rather than `Facades\App\Model\Structures::get()` somehow gets lost in translation.

Comment: they are different queries, maybe one isn't returning any results

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That was my initial thought. They both return results. I've checked.

Comment: then there isn't enough to go off of here .. you pass a collection to this method, if it not empty then the `foreach` would run (iterate it), so based on what you are showing the collection would have to be empty to not reach that log statement

Comment: [2020-10-04 08:13:42] local.INFO: fillCat: data = [{"id":11,"parent_id":null,"category":"Structure","type":"Lampole","subType":null,"variant":null,"description":"Lampole"},{"id":13,"parent_id":11,"category":"Structure","type":"Lampole","subType":"QB","variant"[2020-10-04 08:13:42] local.INFO: fillCat: data = [{"id":297,"category":"Buildings","typeId":297,"type":"Cabin","subTypeId":null,"subType":null,"variantId":null,"variant":null},{"id":311,"category":"Buildings","typeId":311,"type":"Guard

Comment: okay so it is reaching it ... so what is the problem?

Comment: I check for empty data:   public function fillCategories ($data = null, $hasCat = true) {

      if (!$data) {
        return null;
      }

Comment: you are not ... you are passing a Collection, it is an object, it will never be `false`, objects are `true` in PHP  .... `$collection->isEmpty()`

Comment: That's the problem! I don't know. The test foreach in just after the database call works. When the same data is passed the the method, the foreach in the method ignores it.

Comment: your comment says it is running ... `fillCat: ...` ... like i said there isn't enough to go off of here as your comments and your code don't match up

Comment: Log::info("fillCat: data = " . json_encode($data)) ;

      foreach ($data as $v):

        Log::info("fillCat forloop: v($v->cat, $v->type, $v->subType, $v->variant)") ; The first log succeeds, the one inside the loop for Structures works, for the DB::table it doesn't.

Comment: oh it changes again ... can you just provide your actual code  .... if the `foreach` is not running then the collection is empty, i don't know what else to you tell you

Comment: The code for fillCategories()? it's quite complex and not relevant, the fact that the Log::info() inside the foreach loop works for Structures:get() and doesn't for DB::table() is the problem. I've checked both are objects and not arrays. Frankly, I'm stumped.

Comment: make another method that you only pass this data to and do the foreach with the log (removing variables from what is happening here) ... call this method instead ... do you get the result you expect?

Comment: Apparently `orderBy` was the issue! (!) If I take it out, `fillCategories() foreach` processes the data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Faiz, apparently `orderBy` was the issue! (!) If I take it out, `fillCategories()` the `foreach` processes the data.

```
$data = DB::table("categories AS t1")
        ->select("t1.id", ...)
          ->leftJoin("categories AS t2", "t2.parent_id", "=", "t1.id")
          ->leftJoin("categories AS t3", "t3.parent_id", "=", "t2.id")
          ->leftJoin("categories AS t4", "t4.parent_id", "=", "t3.id")
            ->whereNull("t1.parent_id")
              ->orderBy("t1.name")
              ->orderBy("t2.name")
              ->orderBy("t3.name")
            ->get() ;
```

This works. Maybe Taylor Otwell can tell me why!